# Intl and mbstring extension error is not showing in cakephp 3.2 in server

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am using cakephp 3.2 .
Here my project is working on local perfectly .
I have uploaded it to live server .In my server I have checked the phpinfo.php page and got that intl and mbstring  extension is not enabled in the server ,but this two error message is not showing .
I am not getting  what is happening .
As extension is not enabled in server so this 2 error message should come.

```html
// You can remove this if you are confident you have intl installed.
if (!extension_loaded('intl')) {
    trigger_error('You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.', E_USER_ERROR);
}

// You can remove this if you are confident you have mbstring installed.
if (!extension_loaded('mbstring')) {
    trigger_error('You must enable the mbstring extension to use CakePHP.', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Any help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this lines in you root **index.php** file to show all errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
```

(overhead this line)

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

Comment: That's what the `debug` and `Error.errorLevel` configuration is there for. Also the errors mentioned in the question should have been written to the logs.